# How do i insert UIImage on UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uiimage, nsdata

I'm trying to display an Animated-GIF image in a UIImageView. Because this way only the first frame is shown i wanted to try a different approach.

UIWebView.

**How can i get an Animated-GIF that is in memory (NSData) to display on a UIWebView with all frames..?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks Thomas for you response, i don't know if it works because i managed to do it myself now..

Been decoding the GIFs for more then a week now and still with no succes so i went from UIImageView to UIWebView and the following code made it work..

```
[self.webView loadData:gifData MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

I've not tried it, but something like this :

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src='data:image/gif;base64,%@' />", [myData base64Value];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil]
```

You'll need a `NSData` category that implements converting to base64, that shouldn't be difficult to find (I've bookmarked http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html)

edit: another way is to decode the gif, so you have an NSArray of the frames : http://pliep.nl/blog/2009/04/iphone_developer_decoding_an_animated_gif_image_in_objc
http://blog.stijnspijker.nl/2009/07/animated-and-transparent-gifs-for-iphone-made-easy/

Comment: Thanks, it works! I translated it to swift

`let imageData = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(ImagesCatalog.Shared.BlueErrorIcon)!).base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

let imageHTML = "<img src='data:image/png;base64,\(imageData)' />"`